# Can I speed up pasting into vim?

Tags: vim, clipboard

I copied a part of the HTML out of a web page and wanted to save it in a file.
For that I started a new `vim`  session in a terminal window, with a (new) filename specified on the commandline, hit <kbd>i</kbd> to get to insert mode and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and waited while `[-- INSERT --]` showed at the bottom and waited...

As `vim` was non-responsive after several seconds, I opened 'Text Editor' from the Applications→Accessoiries menu pasted the text (which showed up within a fraction of a second, saved it under a new name, closed, and killed the Vim session that still was not done, 1.5 minutes later.
The amount of text was 186K in 3200 lines, not excessive I would say, nor with overly long lines.

Is there a way to speed up these kind of insertions in `vim` and/or is there an explanation why this is so slow compared to using the, otherwise horrible and mouse oriented, Text Editor?

(The %CPU according to `top` doesn't come above 5%, although I have some processors free in the system, so it might be some I/O bound problem, that doesn't exist when reading the same text from a file)

Version info:
Ubuntu 12.04
Vim: 7.3, with patches as supplied by Ubuntu 12.04
bash: 4.2.25
gnome-terminal: 3.4.1.1

Comment: I think it's slow b/c it's having to parse the input and try to format it etc. I'm not sure of the option to do this but would assume you could temporarily disable that feature w/in `vim`, do the pasting, and then re-enable it.  Also try using the `:set paste` feature to see if it improves things. See `:help paste` it describes how `vim` makes no distinction b/w typing and pasting.

Comment: I would expect `vi` to try to parse the file when reading in (after saving the way @l0b0 suggested), as well. But that works fast.

Comment: True, but I'm imagining that it has to reparse everything it's already parsed + the new character as you're pasting it in. That seems to be what's going on when you edit a file too, to a degree.

Comment: the `:set paste` doesn't seem to really make a difference (I am not using a stopwatch, just the wall-clock).

Comment: OK, was just a thought...

Comment: Try `:set nosm` to turn off showmatch. Then vim won't spend time moving the cursor back to a matching opening bracket, paren, etc, sleeping a second, and then moving the cursor back to the input point.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Just tried that, but no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To save a lot of clipboard text to file quickly, you can run `cat > file.txt`, paste the contents, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

If you have [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel) installed, you can do `:r !xsel` to insert the "primary" (aka. "mouse") selection in Vim, or `:r !xsel -b` to insert the "clipboard" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>) buffer. You can also save the selection directly to a file with `xsel >file.txt` or `xsel -b >file.txt`. This removes the need for separate pasting + EOF actions, and avoids printing the entire copy buffer in the terminal.

If you have no xsel but xclip, the corresponding commands are `xclip -out` for the primary selection, or `xclip -out -selection clipboard` for the clipboard buffer.

Comment: Thanks, that at least works without having to revert to the mouse, and inserting the file into vim (e.g. when I don't start with an empty file) is quick enough.

Comment: I don't understand why this couldn't be binded to ctrl+shift+v there is absolutely no sense in all of this.

Comment: BEWARE!!! If the text you're pasting contains any shell variables (starting with $), the shell (bash, zsh, etc.) will try to expand it, and if the variable by that name does not exist, the corresponding text will be lost.

For example, if the pasted content has a $xyz, the shell will replace that with the value of the shell variable named xyz, and if the shell variable xyz does not exist, your resulting text will NOT contain the $xyz.

Comment: This answer is dangerous, and can result in loss of data. See the sibling comment that starts with BEWARE.

Comment: `cat > file.txt`, `:r !xsel` and `xclip -out -selection clipboard` all work for me with the string `echo $foo`. I don't know exactly what you're doing @GurjeetSingh, but please be more specific if you're going to say there's information loss.

Comment: My bad. I was using the `cat > file << EOF` variant, ending the pasted buffer with the string `EOF`, and that causes data loss. The suggestion in the answer, which ends the pasted text with a `ctrl+d` does not have this problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is a buffer flush-to-disk problem. Vim tries to keep your work safe and doesn't assume you can type several thousand characters per second. Read `:help swap-file` for some details on the buffering. The solution to your problem is this:

Turn off vim's swapfile either with:

```
vim -n <your file>
```

or from within vim before the paste:

```
:set noswapfile
```

See `:help swapfile` for more details.

Another option is to simply turn off the syncing to disk of the swap file with `:set swapsync=` but this option takes more keystrokes to undo and I'm lazy. :)

**Turning off swap is not safe for normal operations!** Immediately after the paste, either use `:set swapfile` or `:set swapsync=fsync` to revert back to normal behavior (though technically, normal behavior might have been *sync* and not *fsync*, check with `:set swapsync?` beforehand if you want to go this route).

Comment: this did not speed up things for me...

Answer (score 1):

If you have `xterm_clipboard` feature, you can use the `*` and `+` registers. These registers interface with the X11 primary selection buffer, and clipboard (respectively).

Thus if you've copied something via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, you can paste it in vim with <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

If you've simply highlighted it without copying, you can paste it with <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.
You can also make the `*` buffer the default buffer by doing `:set clipboard=unnamed`. Then any yank (<kbd>y</kbd>), paste (<kbd>p</kbd>), etc, that doesn't specify a register will use the `*` register. Vim 7.3.74 also added `clipboard=unnamedplus`, which will use the `+` register by default.

You can also copy things into the primary selection & clipboard buffers by yanking, for example: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.

Note, that as mentioned, these capabilities all need the `xterm_clipboard` feature. You can see if you have this feature by doing `:version` inside vim, or `vim --version` from the shell, and look for `+xterm_clipboard`. If it says `-xterm_clipboard`, you do not have it and would have to recompile vim.

Comment: I don't have that feature. Would recompiling help even vim is not running under xterm? (I am using gnome-terminal).

Comment: @Anthon If you're using GUI VIM, then I believe the registers are also enabled. `xterm_clipboard` is only if running vim from terminal.

Comment: This is text only, no GUI VIM, but not running from `xterm`.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread. Yes `xterm_clipboard` applies to any terminal emulator, not just xterm. I myself use urxvt.